Receiving the WhiteSource Task warning in the azure devops build pipeline
I have the below WhiteSource task in my build pipeline:
          - task: whitesource.WhiteSource-azure-devops-services.bolt.wss.WhiteSource@21
            inputs:
              cwd: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

The Project code belongs to Node 18.x version so Whenever I build the pipeline, it starts giving me this error from 1 month onwards i.e.,
##[warning]Task 'Mend (formerly WhiteSource)' version 21 (WhiteSource@21) is dependent 
on a Node version (10) that is end-of-life. Contact the extension owner for an updated
 version of the task.Task maintainers should review Node upgrade guidance

Not Sure how to resolve this error?
I tried googling about the compatibility version of WhiteSource (Mend) tool to Node JS but no information found.

Just update your task to a newer version instead of 21, or just use Mend Bolt instead https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whitesource.whiteSource-bolt-v2

https://i.imgur.com/QkFVj30.png If I see my devops organization extensions, it is showing the 22.x version. So can i use it in the task of my build pipeline. If yes, how to use it, should i have to replace @21 with @22

@VivekAnandChakravarthy, The 22.xx you see from the Extension details section is the version number of the extension, not the version number of the pipeline task contained in the extension. One extension can contain multiple pipeline tasks, and each pipeline task might have different update version than others.

I can get the same warning when running the whitesource.WhiteSource-azure-devops-services.bolt.wss.WhiteSource@21 task in my Azure Pipelines.

The reason of this warning is that the current task is depended on Node v10 which is end-of-life. The warning is from the task itself.
You need to contact support from the publisher of this extension, and ask the team to update the extension to use the higher Node version which is not end-of-life.


